# Can Salesforce help if you're a ISO 9001 cetrified company?

Tags: apex

we're a ISO 9001:2008 certified company (50+ SF-users), and I was wondering if there were ideas / apps who could help to do are 'registering' our complaints from customers, and automatically have the follow up (sending info to the internal responsible / reminders / feedback to the person who registered the complaint, etc...).
Can anyone help me on this one?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why wouldn't the case functionality work? There is the ability to perform a web-to-Case which would route based on predefined rules and could also send a message confirmation back to the submitter. The key is how deep the customer much "register" and if they need to be able to track their submission. Yes, Salesforce can do this with several out-of-the-box methods.

Answer (score 0):

Not really a coding question, but you might want to have a look at Salesforce Customer Portal in combination with Service Cloud.

http://www.salesforce.com/ap/crm/customer-service-support/customer-self-service-portal/

Comment: Thank you for this information. However we would want the 'cases' to be filled in by our own sales-people, or other collegues of our company, and not by our customers themselves.